# Tag names showing in spoilers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, spoilers

I have added a hint to my puzzle, and I wanted to cite the tags used to tag the puzzle.

Of course, the hint had to be spoilerised. However, when I posted, it displayed like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45269/ridd%C3%85l-another-unfinished-flat-pack-puzzle) (scroll down to see the hint).

Is there a way to make the tag invisible if the spoiler tag hasn't yet been revealed?

(I can't make an example on meta because the background tag colour is the same as the background spoiler colour, so it doesn't show up)

Note: it seems to have changed now, see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52440/electronic-surveillance-report-1706). Out of curiosity, when did this change?

Comment: I'm closing this question at request of boboquack: it is no longer reproducible.

Comment: @Deusovi If this bug no longer occurs, surely it's [meta-tag:status-completed] (something changed in the SE code to fix it) rather than [meta-tag:status-norepro]? Because it definitely *did* occur at one time.

Answer (score 5):

No, this isn't possible with standard markdown yet.

---

I think the developers forgot to include a special CSS-rule for tags. Generally only the color of text will be transitioned to be "invisible" (i.e. the same color as the spoiler-block):

```
.spoiler {
    transition:color .5s ease-in;
    color:#FFF9E3
}
.spoiler:hover {
    color:#2f3337;
    transition:color .5s ease-in
}
```

For example, in order to hide an image, the following declarations were added:

```
.spoiler img {
    visibility:hidden
}
.spoiler:hover img {
    visibility:visible
}
```

---

All I can offer is a simple userscript which toggles the `opacity` of the tags at least in your browser: Here's the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/LukasRotter/SE-Hide-Tags-In-Spoilers/blob/master/hide-tags-in-spoilers.user.js).

<sub>Note: I didn't use `GM_addStyle` because I wasn't sure if any add-ons except GreaseMonkey support it.</sub>

[image]